# How do I deal with Molotovs

Tags: fallout-4

Going through the game slowly starting to hate having to deal with raiders and others like them as they all seem to carry infinite Molotov Cocktails and throw them at an alarming rate. I would really like to know if anyone has found a way to deal with this? Seems this will be the hardest part of the game for me as it is the only way I die and now have to take a detour around a camp as there are just to many of them throwing Molotov every few seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to line your armor with asbestos, which makes you immune to being set on fire. This is available with the Armor perk, rank 1, at the Armor workshop:

[image: asbestos lining]

[It is also possible to shoot down projectiles with V.A.T.S](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/244027/52800).

Answer (score 1):

I have watched a couple videos regarding this problem based on what I have seen the best method to deal with Molotovs is to kill them with stealth tactics. Or just keep moving since as of now the fire goes through cover most the time so basically move from from one point of cover to another after shooting for a bit rather then just sitting in one spot like you would normally do. Also helps to be at range so you can see when they throw it so you know its time to move. Keep trying different tactics rather then sticking with just one tactic each enemy type has a different AI behavior so its logical the same tactic wont work with every enemy.

I hope this response helped you in some way keep experimenting and you will figure it out.

Comment: Yah I would consider myself pretty good at stealth tactics, unfortunately not far enough along where I can just sneak into their camp and kill them in close range. This camp in particular had some really nice cover, and was hard to get a shot on one after taking out the first one. I have found that looking for a chain link fence or a low ceiling for cover works best so far. otherwise I ignore them and come back

Answer (score 1):

You can sneak up and kill people before they throw, you can shoot them out of the air (VATS or not), or...

[Line your armor with asbestos](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_4_armor_mods).

An asbestos lined armor gives decent energy resist, and makes you immune to being set on fire.

Answer (score 0):

You can shoot Molotov with VATS, when then throw one go in VATS and you can destroy it midair. Also move around a lot if you run out of AP.