# Can you shoot down nuclear projectiles mid-flight?

Tags: fallout-4

[image: animated GIF described below]

I saw the [above short video clip](https://i.imgur.com/fU1HGV1.webm) which depicts a player getting very disappointed at the sight of a nuke flying towards them, while scoped in a sniper rifle. The video is supposed to show how there is nothing you can do to avoid getting destroyed, but I've found contradicting comments on the internet that say you totally can shoot down the nuke using VATS. Can't check this myself yet.

So can you shoot down nuclear projectiles in real time, with VATS, or is it impossible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Yes, you can shoot projectiles and grenades using V.A.T.S.](http://www.gamepur.com/guide/21144-list-fallout-4-tips-and-tricks-how-activate-wait-feature-remove-mods-weapon.html).

You can even shoot the mini nuke carried by suicidal Super Mutants as they're running towards you as an easier method of killing them, but as it's probably better to kill them without detonating the mini nuke so you can loot it!

Comment: I'm sure this is going to take a few attempts, just don't go nuclear while trying!

Comment: Its worth noting that hitting the nuke is an *easy* way of killing super mutant suiciders,but not the most profitable. If you kill a super mutant suicider without the mini nuke detonating, you can loot the mini nuke. This is the only way I have found to aquire mini nukes without relying on the few stashes pre-generated in the game

Comment: I have personally shot missiles, nukes, and other projectiles out of the air in and out of VATS and will confirm the claim: totally possible.

Comment: OTOH, blowing up the mininuke guarantees the SupeMute will drop nuclear material, arguably more valuable early on.

Answer (score 1):

You can shoot the Mini Nukes that Suiciders carry, and you can shoot thrown grenades, but sadly, you cant shoot Mini Nukes out of the air, so, no saving yourself once its been shot.

Edit: Just saw the date you posted that lol.

Comment: date doesn't matter, thanks for the info!